# delayed_job not sending emails but processes job

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, delayed-job

I am using the code example from delayed_job to send out a newsletter:

```
class NewsletterJob < Struct.new(:subscribers)
  def perform
    subscribers.each { |subscriber| NewsletterMailer.newsletter(subscriber.id) }
  end
end
```

Then I set the job here:

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue NewsletterJob.new(Subscriber.find(:all))
```

If I don't use delayed job the mail gets sent so it work.
If I use delayed job directly the mail gets sent as follows:

```
NewsletterMailer.delay.newsletter(subscriber)
```

In the jobs table in the database the following is the yaml:

```
--- !ruby/struct:NewsletterJob
subscribers:
- !ruby/ActiveRecord:Subscriber
  attributes:
    id: '54'
    email: someemail@gmail.com
    created_at: '2013-08-09 04:44:51.113258'
    updated_at: '2013-08-09 08:26:05.934564'
    token: quVI0dhxyyentB7TJ1IO6w
- !ruby/ActiveRecord:Subscriber
  attributes:
    id: '56'
    email: another@gmail.com
    created_at: '2013-08-11 09:29:22.000829'
    updated_at: '2013-08-11 09:29:22.000829'
    token: a-n-yijwi38_HvGFSmetmA
```

I use a MockSMTP to get emails on my local machine.

For some reason even if the works seem to process the job the emails are not being sent.

Is there something wrong with the yaml?

Any assistance appreciated I'm a NOOB

Comment: What kind of mail setup do you have locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you chain `delayed` in front of a mailer method, you don't need to call `deliver` on it. Delayed::Job takes care of that for you.

```
NewsletterMailer.delay.newsletter(subscriber) # No need to call `deliver` here
```

But when you call it from your own custom job struct, you need to remember to call the mailer's `deliver` method:

```
subscribers.each do |subscriber|
  NewsletterMailer.newsletter(subscriber.id).deliver # You need `deliver` here
end
```

Comment: I changed the code to do as you advised but it still does not send out the email. The job seems to be processed as it is taken out of the jobs table after a few seconds. However no email is sent

Comment: Did you restart your Rails server/background process before trying again? Delayed::Job will cache your code until you restart.

Answer (score 0):

In the end it turns that I needed to name the job class using camel case and put it in the lib directory.

```
#lib
NewsletterJob.rb
```

Then in #application.rb I had to turn off the auto deleting of failed jobs to see what was going on and also preload the file from the lib

```
Delayed::Worker.destroy_failed_jobs = false
require "#{Rails.root.to_s}/lib/NewsletterJob.rb"
```

Its all based on the answer here 
[Delayed_job not executing the perform method but emptying the job queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552289/delayed-job-not-executing-the-perform-method-but-emptying-the-job-queue?rq=1)

Comment: I keep my jobs in `lib/jobs` and put this line in `config/initializers/delayed_job.rb` to require all files from that directory: `Dir[Rails.root.join("lib/jobs/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }`. Just a suggestion!